# How are different GPS accuracies related?

Tags: android, ios, geolocation, gps

I'm analyzing GPS data.
My assumption has always been, that the accuracy of the speed variable should be closely related - if not functionally dependent on - the accuracy of the horizontal position and altitude.

However, for the data I've been collecting this is not the case.

Could anyone elaborate on how the accuracies of GPS signals are related with each other?

Background information:
I used smartphones and their built-in GPS-technologies to collect the data. I used both Android (several models) and iOS phones.
I know, that GPS data will always be associated with uncertainty and that the readings are estimations of the position and the accuracy. That being said, in my opinion the estimations would still be related since I don't suppose Apple or Google would add some kind of stochastic noise to their estimation.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  The US government provides some information on GPS accuracy [here](https://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/).  Essentially although your position may be accurate to only 5 or 10m, subsequent position measurements are very accurate relative to each other.  Since you have an accurate distance travelled and an accurate time difference (GPS is based on accurate time) you an calculate accurate speed.

Comment: Interesting question, but offtopic, and possibly very long to answer. "GPS" now uses more then just GPS (check a phone GPS in a tunnel). And speed is often an average (and it depends on more points). Note: I do not think it is Google or Apple, but ubox and others hardware providers.